# IOS - Live Activities In SwiftUI is reopening live activity when i close and reopen the app

Tags: ios, swiftui, widgetliveactivity

I have an app in SwiftUI. When i enter the app i create a simple live activity. Everything works as expected. When I close the app the live activity still works and that's the intended behaviour but when I reopen the app another live activity is created.

How can I get a reference to the first live activity that i created so I would not have two?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can access the currently running live activities on app start with

`Activity<ContentAttributes>.activities` (optionally filter them or use the first one if you only have one). Only if there is no activity running you should start a new one.

See [Apple's documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/activitykit/activity/activities) for more info.